# Regex group match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working

```
<div class="entry">The company with Co. Reg. No 1241515 will...</div>
```

How can I match anything that looks like `Co. Reg. No <number>` in a `div.entry` and add a link to the entire phrase, where the link includes the number?

This is what I've got so far...

```
$( "div.entry" ).html(function() {
  var re = /(Co\. Reg\. No ([d]+))/;
  html = $(this).html().replace(re, "<a href='http://companylookup.com/$1'>" + $0 + "</a>");
  return html;
});
```

But it's not working - I think my group logic is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have parentheses around the whole thing, `$1` refers to the whole match, and `$2` is the number (or it would be if you did `\d` instead of `[d]`).

Try:

```
var regex = /Co\. Reg\. No (\d+)/;
var replace = "<a href='http://companylookup.com/$1'>$&</a>";
```

In this case I've removed the redundant parentheses (which makes `$1` the number part again), and used the correct `$&` to refer to the whole match.

Comment: Ah - the `\d` was the problem, and so was not realising that group indexing starts at 1 not 0! Thanks very much for your help.